# Basic implementation of ajax in magento

Tags: magento

I am a newbie in magento and trying to implement ajax,but can't find a proper tutorial to follow. Could anyone provide me some reference or guide me to where i would be able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a tutotial but I can explain you bit what I implemented in a project a month back.

I created a controller on which we can fire an AJAX request on a specific action. In this case the `getoptionsAction` in the `IndexController` of our custom `Offerte` module.

The `getoptionsAction` in my controller takes a `product_id` and loads the options for the product. It builds the HTML and echo's this on function end.

In phtml file I have following code to invoke the AJAX request and update html-object in frontend:

```
function get_options(prod_id){
    var product_options = $('product_options');
    var prod_id = $('product').getValue();
    new Ajax.Updater('product_options', 
        '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>offerte/index/getoptions', 
        { method: 'get',parameters: {prod_id: prod_id, type: 'get_regular_options' } ,
        onCreate: function(){
            $('loading-img-options').show();
        },
        onComplete: function (t) {
            $('loading-img-options').hide();
            $('product_options').show();
        }
    });
}
```

the above function uses Ajax.Updater. You can also use Ajax.Request to get the result to juggle with.

```
function stripslashes(str) {
    return str.replace(/\\'/g,'\'').replace(/\"/g,'"').replace(/\\\\/g,'\\').replace(/\\0/g,'\0');
}

function get_products(){
    product = $('product');
    cat_id = $('category').value;
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>offerte/index/getproducts', 
        {method: 'get', parameters: {cat_id: cat_id, mode: 'offerte'},
        onCreate: function(){
            $('product-loading').show();
            $('product_options').hide();
        },
        onSuccess: function(t) {
            resp = jQuery.parseJSON(t.responseText);
            $('prod-container').innerHTML = resp.options ? stripslashes(resp.options) : '<?php echo $this->__('No options found') ?>';
            $('product-loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

(please note I use JQuery to parseJSON. You can also use String.evalJSON, but I was lazy here :-)
Using Ajax.Request you need to return the result from the controller as JSON. I used the code below in my controller to return JSON to our phtml to use in the onSuccess Callback function above:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
```

Hope this is of any help